# Cast lambda in delegate

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to do exactly the [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235243/using-reflection-call-a-method-of-a-field-on-an-object-that-already-exists) but with Where (not Add). Visual Studio told me to cast it in delegate or in tree type, but I'm stuck with that, when I try to cast it, it doesn't work. Can somebody gives me a short example of how to cast the lambda expression in delegate ?

Thank you!

Sorry for late edit.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult test()
{
    Contexte contexte = new Contexte();
    var listField = contexte.GetType().GetField("<offreStages>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    dynamic fldVal = listField.GetValue(contexte);



    fldVal.Where(os => os.id == 1);
    /* Error:
    Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
    dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or
    expression tree type.
    */

    return View();
}
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235243/using-reflection-call-a-method-of-a-field-on-an-object-that-already-exists), it says we can use dynamic to directly call method without complicated Invoke, but as you can see, it doesn't work if we need to send a lambda expression and I just don't understand the error (how to cast it). Can somebody explain it and give me an example ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve] of the problem - it's really hard to help when we've only get a vague description of what you're trying to do, and no indication of what's going wrong beyond "it doesn't work".

Comment: Please show us what you are attempting to do, with *your* code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452261/how-do-i-invoke-an-extension-method-using-reflection

Comment: Based on what little information you've provided, I'm _guessing_ that you want to use `typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)` instead of calling `GetType()` on an object instance, call `GetMethod("Where")` (specifying appropriate parameter types to get the overload you want), and then invoke that `MethodInfo` as would otherwise be used in the other examples you've seen. But it's impossible to know for sure, never mind exactly what that would look like without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code, or if you really need to also include a text copy of the code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'll do that in future post, thanks for the tip ! :)

Comment: How about do it in this post...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Clearly not here today sorry, edited with code sample and error from visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally spoken, the compiler is confused about the *type of the lambda expression*. Either cast it or use a constuctor to clarify. But in this case [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) is in fact an extension method to `IEnumerable`s, defined in the class `Enumerable` (note the difference!). Change your code as follows:

```
Contexte contexte = new Contexte();
var listField = contexte.GetType().GetField("<offre_Stages>_k__BackingField", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
// either:
IEnumerable<OS> fldVal = (IEnumerable<OS>)listField.GetValue(contexte); // don't use ``dynamic`` as we know it's an ``IEnumerable`1``
fldVal.Where(os => os.id == 1);
// or:
dynamic fldVal = listField.GetValue(contexte);
Enumerable.Where((IEnumerable<OS>)fldVal, os => os.id == 1); // explicit call to the extension method
```